# Pyspark Dataframe Column - Convert Decimal values represented as string in column

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I have the below Pyspark dataframe with Column_1 as string

```
S.No.      Column_1
1          1.0
2          1.0
3          2.0
4          N
5          N
6          3.0
7          N
```

I have to convert the numbers in column 1 from 1.0, 2.0 etc to just 1 or 2 or 3. I have to truncate the decimal places. I cannot cast it into int because it has string values too.

Expected Output:

```
S.No.      Column_1
1          1
2          1
3          2
4          N
5          N
6          3
7          N
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you can use `regexp_replace` here:

```
df.withColumn("test",F.regexp_replace(F.col("Column_1"),'[.].?','')).show()
```

---

```
+-----+--------+----+
|S.No.|Column_1|test|
+-----+--------+----+
|    1|     1.0|   1|
|    2|     1.0|   1|
|    3|     2.0|   2|
|    4|       N|   N|
|    5|       N|   N|
|    6|     3.0|   3|
|    7|       N|   N|
+-----+--------+----+
```